# Why is running R code inside a function faster?

Tags: r

Consider the following examples:

```
> start<-Sys.time()
> for(i in 1:10000){}
> Sys.time()-start
Time difference of 0.01399994 secs
> 
> fn<-function(){
+   start<-Sys.time()
+   for(i in 1:10000){}
+   Sys.time()-start
+ }
> fn()
Time difference of 0.00199604 secs



start<-Sys.time()
for(i in 1:10000){x<-100}
Sys.time()-start
Time difference of 0.012995 secs
fn<-function(){
  start<-Sys.time()
  for(i in 1:10000){x<-100}
  Sys.time()-start
}
fn()
Time difference of 0.008996964 secs
```

The result is the same after increasing number of iterations as shown below:

```
> sim<-10000000
> start<-Sys.time()
> for(i in 1:sim){x<-i}
> Sys.time()-start
Time difference of 2.832 secs
> 
> fn<-function(){
+   start<-Sys.time()
+   for(i in 1:sim){x<-i}
+   Sys.time()-start
+ }
> fn()
Time difference of 2.017997 secs
```

I am guessing this is not a coincidence! Why does R code run faster in a function?

Comment: Please accept user2554330's answer if applicable (not only to give credits but also to help other readers to find the answer easily). THX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in R are compiled by the JIT compiler.  After this happens, most functions will be faster.

As the docs in `?compiler::enableJIT` say,

> JIT is disabled if the argument is 0. If level is 1 then
> larger closures are compiled before their first use. If level  is 2,
> then some small closures are also compiled before their  second use.
> If level is 3 then in addition all top level loops  are compiled
> before they are executed. JIT level 3 requires the  compiler option
> optimize to be 2 or 3. The JIT level can also  be selected by starting
> R with the environment variable  R_ENABLE_JIT set to one of these
> values. Calling enableJIT with  a negative argument returns the
> current JIT level. The default  JIT level is 3.

So many functions will be faster than top level code.

Comment: So to prove that this is really the reason here  the code under benchmark could be compiled and executed and should show the same timing then like if it was contained in a function...

Comment: It's probably easier to set the JIT level to 0 and see if that removes the difference.

Answer (score 4):

To prove the JIT-impact I have used this benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)

compiler::enableJIT(0)  # use 3 for testing with full JIT compiler

fn <- function() {
   for(i in 1:10000) {}
}

microbenchmark(for_loop_without_func = for(i in 1:10000) {},
               for_loop_in_func = fn(),
               times = 100)

# Run eg. with (to avoid RStudio or other overhead):
# R --vanilla < jit_test.R
```

The result shows that with disabled JIT the execution time is nearly the same:

```
Unit: microseconds
                  expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
 for_loop_without_func 180.619 180.7990 182.7129 180.9290 181.050 239.489   100
      for_loop_in_func 182.582 182.7075 186.2232 182.7625 182.938 309.912   100
```

With `compiler::enableJIT(3)` (which is the default) the function is faster:

```
Unit: microseconds
                  expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 for_loop_without_func 558.727 574.4875 659.21931 657.3425 702.6475 1984.351   100
      for_loop_in_func  53.019  53.4955  61.59588  53.7260  54.0320  790.632   100
```

Interestingly enabling JIT seems to slow down the code running outside of the function (compared to the first "no JIT" benchmark) even though it will not be optimized. Would be interesting to understand why (perhaps JIT needs time to find out which code it will not optimize)?

Comment: surprisingly, if inside the brackets I calculate `{sqrt(123)}`, the function seems slower

Comment: @Waldi I have tested this with JIT level 0 and 3 and the results are the same in my case (function is faster with JIT 3). Have you added the `sqrt` expression in both places (function and microbenchmark call?)