# R function speed confusion using microbenchmark

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I want to write a function to calculate the euclidean distance between two points.

I wrote two routines, One seems to be faster when measured using microbenchmark, But as soon as I wrap them in a function, One routine stays the same in execution time while the other routine becomes faster than the expression itself, which I am baffled with.

```
xy1 = c(-1,-13)
xy2 = c(-17,-26)
distXY1 = function() return(sqrt((xy2[1] - xy1[1]) ^ 2 + (xy2[2] - xy1[2]) ^ 2))
distXY2 = function() return(sqrt(sum((xy2-xy1)^2)))
microbenchmark(
  sqrt((xy2[1]-xy1[1])^2 + (xy2[2]-xy1[2])^2),
  distXY1(),
  sqrt(sum((xy2-xy1)^2)),
  distXY2(),
  times=100000
)
```

Output

```
Unit: nanoseconds
                                            expr min  lq     mean median  uq     max neval
 sqrt((xy2[1] - xy1[1])^2 + (xy2[2] - xy1[2])^2) 287 369 447.2313    369 410 1176085 1e+05
                                       distXY1()  82 123 173.7059    164 164 1881490 1e+05
                        sqrt(sum((xy2 - xy1)^2)) 123 205 254.1065    205 205 1133363 1e+05
                                       distXY2() 123 205 257.6268    205 246 2316008 1e+05
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859458/why-is-running-r-code-inside-a-function-faster

Comment: Thanks, Understood what was going on now.